# In Python, how no explicitly return function changes the data in another function?

Tags: python

[Python Code is here:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0MNDd.png)

In the parse_subject function call, the first tuple passed in the word_list has 'stop' word_type.

I passed this list to the function parse_subject. Then within this function, after the execution of skip function I find word_list length shortened as that very tuple no longer exists within the word_list.
So the word_list available to the called peek function is this new word_list.

Consider that match function return values to skip function. But skip function does not return anything explicitly.

I want to ask that when skip function does not return anything explicitly, then how the word_list value in the parse_subject gets updated after the execution of skip function as we could see that the updated word_list then is further used in the called peek function within the parse_subject function.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the following line in match function

`word = word_list.pop(0)`

please note that python passes objects by reference, this is what causes the original list to be modified as well.

[More info about Pop method](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html)

Comment: Python is not "pass by reference" in the strict sense. It's actually "pass by object reference", see https://robertheaton.com/2014/02/09/pythons-pass-by-object-reference-as-explained-by-philip-k-dick/.